# Create an elasticsearch Property from a FieldType

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to create an Elasticsearch Property object from a FieldType. The only way I have found to do this is to write a very long switch statement along the following lines:

```
public Property type2prop(FieldType type) {
   if (type == FieldType.Keyword) {
      prop = Property.of(p -> p.keyword(k -> k));
   } else if (type == FieldType.Boolean) {
      prop = Property.of(p -> p.boolean(b -> b));
   } // and so on...
}
```

This seems ludicrous to me. There are over 20 possible values for FieldType, and who knows if ES won't add new ones in the future.

Isn't there a more direct way of creating a Property object from a FieldType object?